# java write to the end of file with new line

Tags: java

I want to write results to the end of the file using java

```
FileWriter fStream;
        try {
            fStream = new FileWriter("recallPresision.txt", true);
            fStream.append("queryID=" + queryID + "         " + "recall=" + recall + "           Pres=" + presision);
            fStream.append("\n");
            fStream.flush();
            fStream.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(query.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

I put `"\n"` in the statement , it writes to the file but not with new line


I want to print results with new line

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The newline sequence is system dependent. On some systems its `\n`, on others it's `\n\r`, `\r\n`, `\r` or something else entirely different. Luckily, Java has a built in property which allows you to access it:

```
 String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

Comment: i make this system.out.println(newLine) but just print new line

Comment: did u mean that to append ur newLine to the end of my query ?

Comment: @LinCR You should replace your `"\n"` with `System.getProperty("line.separator")`

Comment: yes it works, thank you very much , i iwll accept your answer after 9min

Answer (score 7):

### Wrong

```
fStream.append("\n");
```

### Right

```
// don't guess the line separator!
fStream.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

Comment: Your welcome.  I notice you chose to accept Jeffrey's answer.  Good call.  :)

Comment: i accepted his answer cos he answers me first , i am really sorry , i hope i could accept more than one answer , really thank you , very thank you

Comment: No need to be sorry.  I agree with your choice.  :)

Answer (score 2):

It does print the newline, what you want is a blank line at the end. Add another `\n`.

Comment: don't guess the line separator!

Answer (score 2):

Try using `\r\n` instead.

Also, you should find that if you open your text file in a rich-text-editor, such as wordpad, your append has actually worked.

Edit: Ignore me. Jeffery and Andrew's answers are much better.

Answer (score 2):

You could also change to:

```
fStream = new FileWriter("recallPresision.txt", true);
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(fStream);
out.println("queryID=" + queryID + "         " + "recall=" + recall + "           Pres=" + presision);
out.flush();
out.close();
fStream.close();
```